# Hiding/showing text for <p class="show"> using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some homework where my objective is to hide and show text for `<p class="show">` and I've really hit a wall.
I've managed to code a toggle button that changes the text when pressed but I can't figure out how to make my text react to it.
Some pointers would be greatly appreciated, just to point me in the right direction.

This is the code I'm using for the button.

```
    function toggle(button)
{
    if(button.value=="Show text")
    {
        button.value="Hide text";
    }
    else
    {
        button.value="Show text";
    }
}
```

My current code is: 
[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/MaxieTheHatter/ordnycsn/14/)

Edit:
Might be worth mentioning I have two text string with the same class name.

Comment: set the `display` style to `none` to hide it, and then to `block` to show it.

Comment: Note that your whole fallback for `getElementsByClassName` is only useful if you want to support IE8 and older. Personally I wouldn't bother anymore, and by the time you're done with school, I think it certainly is too old to care.

Comment: [Here is one for inspiration](https://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/bxyv1utg/2/). It uses some 'modern' features and therefore won't work in IE9-. But then again, you would want to mess with it and make it your own anyway. Anyway, I've added a bunch of comments to describe the working and some decisions. It's just my take on the issue, rather than a solution to your problem, so that's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Great reply there Golez, even though I didn't end up using your examples I got some ideas from it.
I managed to get the code working although it feels a bit rough, will have to polish it later.
Note: the text is in swedish but the code is mostly in swedish [Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/MaxieTheHatter/ordnycsn/21/)
Although... the code works in my browser but for some reason the text isnt defaulted to hide on JSFiddle. Wierd.

Comment: How silly of me, meant to write that the code is mostly in ENGLISH not swedish.